# Repair bootloader

Tags: live-usb, bootloader, iso

I need help to repair the bootloader. In [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) first option, live USB I have downloaded the ISO file and **Universal USB Installer**, but at the start the program asks me to choose the file type, and I don't understand what is the correct file. What should I choose?

[image]

Comment: Please upload a screenshot. Are you sure it isn't asking you for the file name simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Universal usb installer you need to select the version of ubuntu and the location of the iso file which you downloaded.

Steps-
1. run Universal usb installer.
2.select linux distribution, for example ubuntu 13.04 (should be same as the iso file you downloaded).
3.select th location where the ISO file is currently, for example in the Downloads folder..
To navigate to where the ISO file is present, click on the browse option in Universal usb installer , and go to the directly where the ISO is present. Then click on it to select it.
4.Select the usb drive letter. (it would show up in your MyComputer)
5.Click on create.

Thats it

Comment: Yes, thanks. But "linux-secure-13.04-64bit" is not a linux version, and so if I select "Ubuntu 13.04 etc." not find in browse my file. What I must select in step 2 "select linux distribution"?

Comment: @Docfb90, If you have the ISO you can skip that step. That step is used to aumatically download the ISO, so if you already have downloaded it you really don't need to do it again!

Comment: How I can skip? (I have the screenshot, I post here (how?) or on imageshack?

Comment: Add the link to your question. And for skipping, notice the last "step".

Comment: got your point..i dont think that the Universal usb installer supports linux secure remix..and on choosing ubuntu 13.04 it tries to find an iso named ubuntu13_04.iso

Comment: I post the link to image. Step 2 is locked until I complete the step 1

Comment: What options does it give you? (Sorry was confusing this program with another one.)

Comment: an option for you to try is- Unlisted Linux ISO (this is the last option in choosing the linux version) and then browse to your location of inux-secure-13.04-64bit

Comment: But in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair is write: "Boot-Repair is also included in Linux-Secure-Remix.
Remark : you can also install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer)." So is wrong adn I must use UnetBootin or LiliUsb?

Comment: Oh yes! is "Unlisted Linux ISO" thanks everybody!!! :)